# Using If statement in AlertifyJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, alertify

i'm trying to use an if statement with **Alertify** but it seems to not work, am i doing something wrong?

```
var Question = alertify.prompt("what is your name?","lenovo")

    if (Question === "lenovo"){

        function(evt, value) 


        { alertify.success('You entered: ' + value) });


    }
```

Comment: How do you know the `if` is not working? I mean there's nothing in the provided code snippet, which would proofe your statement. Check also the console, there's an error message waiting for you.

Comment: Hi! Here is an equivalent js CODE: var Question = prompt("what is your name?");
if (Question === "John"){
    document.write(" that's me!");
}else{
    
    document.write(" that's NOT me!");
}

Comment: What is the purpose of the function declaration(?) within the `if` block? Notice, that it triggers an error, the name of the function is missing. But even if there was a name for the declared function, there's nothing in the snippet that would express a non-working `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prompt declaration is not the correct way, what you need to do instead is the following :

```
alertify.prompt("what is your name?", "lenovo",
    function(evt, value) {
        if (value === "lenovo") {
            alertify.success('You entered: ' + value);
        }
    },
    function() {
        alertify.error('Cancel')
    }
);
```

Note that you do not necessarely need the second function if you do not wish to handle the user clicking the Cancel button.

Answer (score 0):

i can solve this problem ,my solution asnyc await function :

Example :

```js
function confirmDialogAsync(message = "", okText="Yes", cancelText="No") {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            alertify.confirm(
                message, 
                () => {resolve(true);},
                () => {resolve(false);}
            )
            .set({ title: " " })
            .set({ labels: { ok: okText, cancel: cancelText } });
        });
      }

const saveControlValidation = async () => {

console.log(1); 

 if (!(await confirmDialogAsync("Hello Salih ŞEKER","Hi","Bye"))) {
               return false;
    }

console.log(2);

}
```